# How do I disable Spring Dashboard on startup on GGTS?

Tags: eclipse, ide, spring-tool-suite, ggts

I recently installed GGTS. It's been good so far but it's starting to annoy me how the dashboard (window) keeps showing up on start up. I checked the preferences but there's nothing there that switches it off. I attempted to uninstall the feature, but the GGTS won't allow me.

Comment: usually if you close the dashboard, shutdown STS/GGTS, and reopen it, the dashboard shouldn't show up again. Is that not the case for you? What version of GGTS do you use?

Comment: That's not what's happening with mine. I'm using GGTS 3.6.2.RELEASE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably running into this bug: [STS-3935](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3935). The dashboard is supposed to stay closed when you close it, but in some situations in STS 3.6.2 it doesn't.

If you upgrade to a newer version of STS the problem should go away. If you do not want to upgrade your STS, you can also try running with JDK 8 (so you'll get the new dashboard which is not subject to the bug).

Or, another workaround suggested in the bug-report is to open manually edit the preferences file at `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui.prefs` and add or change the line:

```
org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.uidashboard.startup=false
```

Read the bug report if you need more details.